# GWT Grid table add a button on another column

Tags: java, button, gwt, datagrid

In a datagrid - lets say I have two columns , what I want to do is when I click a button on column B it will create a button on column A. The more I click, the more button it will create.

is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess the most easy would be to already have the button B created but with a setVisible(false) so you could make it visible with the method onClick of the button A.

Comment: the problem is you don't know how many times the user will click the button

Comment: Do you have a table or ... what you mean when you say column? I mean, if you can make a .add to this column and add a new component you could declare and instantiate a new button each onClick and .add(yourButton) to the column.

Comment: its a datarid -question edited for clarity. Hmmm, so i will call column A then add an object on it? if this is possible it will be a custom column